# Jedi Survivor Deluxe Edition: access bonus content from other local accounts?

Tags: ps5, star-wars-jedi-survivor

My son pre-ordered *Jedi Survivor: Deluxe Edition* on PS5 through the PlayStation Store. I guess he bought it through my account as it’s the “parent” account, and his is a child’s account. He can access the game just fine, but all the bonus content (skins, bonus weapons etc.) are only available when we play the game on my account. Is there a way to transfer them or give him access to them?

From this experience, it seems you get two versions of the game; the standard one and the deluxe version. On my profile I can choose to start either version. On his, he can only choose the standard one.

Comment: As of May 17 2023 on PC, Patch 5 addresses the issue of collectors edition items.
> More robust detection of pre-order and deluxe content in-game, preventing players from only randomly having access to the content.

Comment: @Neon1024 Thanks. I’ll see if it helps. I’ve had short shrift on this from both EA and Sony support. EA didn’t even respond to the ticket and Sony said “yep, that’s how it’s supposed to be”. Great.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to talk to EA about that, as far as I know all the cosmetics would stay on the account that made the purchase. But playing the game on the console shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: What is your last sentence in reference to? Whether or not it's playable on console is not the issue here.